# WordPress Gravity Form listing on Frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I need Gravity Form author to view and edit the records at frontend. For that I have integrated Gravity Forms Sticky List.

I am able to list the records but View and Edit Buttons not working.

**Records are as follows:**

[image]

**Sticky List shortcode (on WP Page):**

`[stickylist id="1"]` 1 is the Gravity Form ID.

**Sticky List Settings as Follows:**

[image]

On **View** and **Edit** buttons a Form is generated but on clicking these buttons, user is redirected to same page. Instead it should perform View and Edit actions.

[image]

I am using latest version of Gravity Forms and Sticky List. Could you please verify if my settings are correct or suggest any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the "Embedd page/post" dropdown is set correctly. It should point to where your form (not the list) is located. Or you can overwrite this setting with using the "Custom url".

Also [Check the Sticky List official FAQ](https://sv.wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-sticky-list/)